# Realm errors: RLMArray and Migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I ran into some errors when I'm trying to compile my realm code, this is the first version of the code:

```
import RealmSwift

class Test: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var dict = Dictionary<String, Int>()
    dynamic var owner: TestList?
}


class TestList: Object{
    dynamic var name = ""
    let tests = List<Test>().filter("ALL Test.dict[hello] != nil")
}

//ViewController

import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let realm = Realm()
        let test1 = Test()
        test1.name = "test1"
        test1.dict = ["hello": 1]
        realm.write{realm.add(test1)}
        let test2 = Test()
        test2.name = "test2"
        test2.dict = ["nihao": 2]
        realm.write{realm.add(test2)}

        let test3 = Test()
        test3.name = "test3"
        test3.dict = ["hello": 3]
        realm.write{realm.add(test3)}
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func set(sender: UIButton){
        let test = Test()
        let realm = Realm()
        test.name = "not using CoreData"
        realm.write{realm.add(test)}
        text = "abc"
    }        

    @IBAction func show(sender: UIButton){

        let test = Realm().objects(TestList)
        var str = ""
        println("got to here")
        for i in test{
            str += " \(i.name)"
        }
        label.text = str
    }
}
```

With this setup I got an error in my log that says:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'This method can only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an RLMRealm'`

When I removed the filtering in my TestList object, the error became: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'Test' due to the following errors:
- Property 'dict' has been added to latest object model.
- Property 'owner' has been added to latest object model.'`

Am I understanding Realm's documentation completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is right. You can't filter on properties. Furthermore Realm doesn't allow Dictionary properties at the moment. You would need to explicitly model that as a list property of a dedicated Realm object entity, which has fields to hold a `String` and an `Int`.

```
class Test: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var dict = List<TestRelatedThing>()
    dynamic var owner: TestList?
}

class TestRelatedThing : Object {
   dynamic var key: String
   dynamic var value: Int
}

class TestList: Object{
    dynamic var name = ""
    let tests = List<Test>()
}
```

You can then query at runtime by:

```
Realm().objects(TestList).filter("ANY tests.key == %@", "hello")
```

*Hint*: The aggregate operator `ALL` is not supported for Realm. See our [predicate cheat sheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) for a full list of supported operators. Here it makes anywhere more sense to existential quantify that operation, because of the changed data structure, which doesn't allow an entry of `TestRelatedThing` with it's `value` property to equal `nil` to exist in the first place. So you can just make sure that there is an entry with key `"hello"` instead.

For the second error: I guess you tried to run your code before and added after that first run further fields to your model objects.

You can reset the simulator state or might just add one of the following lines of code to ensure to start with a fresh Realm on each run while development.

```
# Swift 1.2
var error: NSError?
NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.defaultPath, error:&error)

# Swift 2
try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.defaultPath)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I was able to fix almost all my errors but I don't quite understand the fix for the last one, it seems that if I don't start with a fresh Realm, the query results would just build up each time it's called. So I end up getting one more set of results each time I run the program.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you don't start with a fresh Realm, your query results contain one result more after each run, because you add objects in your `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller. Those changes are **persisted**. That's what you use Realm for after all, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and my class was similar to your TestList class using a List object. To fix it, I needed to change the dynamic to @Persisted and the "let" to a var on the List. I am using Swift 5 with Xcode 14.2. Using your TestList class, I applied the similar fix to my code with yours:

```
class TestList: Object{
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var tests = List<Test>().filter("ALL Test.dict[hello] != nil")
}
```

Hope this is helpful!